# how to check the app is open used referral code and how to get the referral data in react native

Tags: react-native, referrals

how to check the app is open used referral code and how to get the referral data  in react native

how to check the app is open used referral code and how to get the referral data  in react native

Comment: You mean deep links?

Comment: I am design react-native app I am generate  referral link how to catch the data when download the app using referral link which method used like deep linking or another thinks

Comment: It might be that you need to add native module to expo (https://forums.expo.dev/t/appsflyer-integration-with-expo/32589/8)
That should allow you to use Appsflyer/Getsocial/Firebase